# Jenkins Multibranch project are not triggered when a SNAPSHOT is built

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have in Jenkins (v2.164.3) different maven projects, which reside in our local gitlab server.

All projects define the following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
node {
    stage('git') {
        checkout scm
    }
    stage('compile') {
        withMaven(mavenSettingsConfig: 'e228f408-7768-4374-b8e1-259321e2fa99') {
            bat "mvn clean compile"
        }
    }
    stage('test') {
        withMaven(mavenSettingsConfig: 'e228f408-7768-4374-b8e1-259321e2fa99') {
            bat "mvn test"
        }
    }
    stage('install') {
        withMaven(mavenSettingsConfig: 'e228f408-7768-4374-b8e1-259321e2fa99') {
            bat "mvn install -DskipTests"
        }
    }
}
```

in the configuration of the multibranch project, the option `Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built` is checked. (The same option in the configuration of the several branches is not checked)

Unfortunately this check seems to be ignored in my case, as when a project (projectX) is build (e.g. the develop branch, that creates a SNAPSHOT jar), all downstream projects (withe their develop branch), that define a dependency in their pom to projectX, are not triggered.

What is wrong ? Or do I need to check the option in all branches of the multibranch project ? Or do I need to change something in my `Jenkinsfile` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [Pipeline Maven Plugin FAQ > My downstream pipelines don't get triggered even if I use "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin#PipelineMavenPlugin-Mydownstreampipelinesdon'tgettriggeredevenifIuse%22BuildwheneveraSNAPSHOTdependencyisbuilt%22)

To configure the Jenkins Pipeline Maven integration to trigger downstream pipelines on "mvn install":

- Either change the global configuration:

  - Navigate to "Manage Jenkins / Global Tools Configuration"
  - Click on "Add Publisher" and select "Pipeline Graph Publisher"
  - In the section "Downstream Pipeline Triggers", change the the "Maven lifecycle threshold" from "deploy" to "install"
    [image: Pipeline Maven Plugin > Global Configuration > Trigger Downstream Pipelines > Maven lifecycle threshold]
- Or in the script of the upstream pipeline, configure `withMaven(options: [pipelineGraphPublisher(lifecycleThreshold: 'install')]) {...}`

Note: regarding your declaration `mavenSettingsConfig: 'e228f408-...'`, please note that you can declare the Maven settings either globally or at the folder level as documented on [Jenkins Pipeline Maven Integration > Features > Maven Settings](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin#PipelineMavenPlugin-DefaultConfiguration)